# (Neo)vim see macro text as it is being recorded

Tags: vim, macros, neovim

So if I'm recording a macro, I sometimes make a silly mistake, or I'll do something and lose track of the previous key that I pressed.

Is it possible to show the state of the current macro that I'm recording, as I'm recording it? (probably in the line at the bottom where vim shows the name of the file)

For example, if I type `qaiNowImRecording`, then I want to be able to see (somewhere) the text `iNowImRecording`. If I continue to type `^[dip` then I want to see `iNowImRecording^[dip`

Comment: The memory buffer in which your keystrokes go during a recording is not exposed at runtime so no, it is not possible. As an alternative to recording, you can use `:normal iNowImRecording`.

Comment: Okay. I'll wait a bit to see if anyone can offer an alternative solution, but just in case that doesn't come up could you post your comment as an answer so that I can accept it as _the_ answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As romainl said it is not possible. But what you can do is view your register with `:reg a` (assuming you recorded using the register a) to then see what you recorded.

Regarding the issue of losing track `:normal` indeed is a good alternative. Or, and that is what I do, you start over.

Comment: Okay thanks, I was hoping there would be a way to get more immediate feedback while still performing the macro in real time, but I guess not.